# Citations on same page?

Tags: citing, classicthesis

I am using `classic-thesis` style for the document, and `\bibliographystyle{kluwer}` . By default all the citations are given in the Bibliography at the end of the document. For example a citation on a given page will be referred by its identifier lets say [Author 2001] when I use the `\cite{author2001}`. The full entry of the citation can be seen in the Bibliography at the end with this identifier [Author 2001]. What I would like is that this entry full entry appear on the same page as where the `\cite{author2001}` command is invoked. Since the `classic-thesis` supports margin notes it would be great if the citations can be present as margin notes, or even in the footnotes and also in the bibliography. Is there any package / hack to achieve this?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The package `biblatex` can do this; looking at the user manual of `biblatex` I additionally found "The `inlinebib` package is designed for traditional citations given in footnotes." I would recommend `biblatex` tough since it's more commonly used.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[autocite=footnote,notetype=foot+end,style=authortitle-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}

\begin{document}
See the \texttt{Biblatex}~\footcite{biblatex} documentation for more information on this.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```
@manual{biblatex,
    author          = {Lehman, Philipp},
    title           = {The {Biblatex} Package},
    subtitle        = {Programmable Bibliographies and Citations},
    month           = {6},
    year            = {2014},
    url             = {http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex},
}
```

This will produce the following output:
[image: Result of the code]

For more information, take a look at the [Biblatex manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am using `tufte-latex` style itself which provides the required style of referencing by default