# Citations in footnotes on the same page, using LyX?

Tags: lyx, citing, footnotes

I am aware that citations on the same page in LaTeX are possible with biblatex ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187190/citations-on-same-page), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139872/biblatex-full-citations-in-footnotes-on-every-page)).

But how do I make them appear automatically as footnotes in LyX, when I add citations using the built-in citation manager?

Answer (score 2):

LyX (till the version 2.2.0) didn't provide native support for BibLaTeX yet, but if you see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex you'll find how to use the built-in citation manager with BibLaTeX with some little tricks.

In pratice you leave the the BibTeX inset (Insert→List/TOC→BibTeX Bibliography...) in a LyX note or comment, in this way LyX thinks you are using BibTeX while you are using BibLaTeX!

Remember to insert `natbib=true` as a BibLaTeX option, it gives the alias for `\citet` and `\citep` (used by the citation manager).

*Update (December, 2017)*

The LyX developers have recently [announced](https://www.lyx.org/News#item1) that from the 2.3.x Series, LyX has native support for BibLaTeX.
By now they have only published a 2.3.0 release candidate, but the official one is coming soon.

Directly from the new feature list:

> Biblatex support is not comprehensive in the sense that each and every
>   of the many features of the package is (already) natively supported
>   via the GUI, but it is now possible to
>
> - select Biblatex alternatively to "Basic", "Jurabib", or "Natbib" in
>     the Document Settings,
> - set bibliography (*.bbx) and citation (*cbx)
>     style files (LyX will propose sensible defaults for author-year and
>     numerical),
> - set arbitrary biblatex package options via a simple line
>     edit widget, 
>     -set options to the \printbibliography command via a
>     simple line edit widget in the Bib(la)TeX inset dialog.

For further details, click [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX23#biblatex).